# Issue when Repeatedly Starting Activities from Service while screen is locked

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have two services "home" and "alert". The home service scans nearby Bluetooth devices for a number (1, 2, or 3). The alert service scans the Bluetooth for a 0.

When a 1, 2, or 3 is scanned, the home service stops, and a new activity is started, depending on the number. The alert service is started.

When a 0 is read, the alert service stops and returns the user to the main activity. The home service is restarted.

My problem, which happens every single time, is the that when I try to start the alert a second time from the phone being locked, the activity won't start up. Please see the list below so you can understand further.

1- Home Service and mainActivity are running in background with phone locked

2- Bluetooth reads in a 1

3- Home Service is stopped, Alert Service Started, Alert Screen 1 activity started

4- Alert Service reads in a 0

5- Alert Service stopped, Home Service Started, mainActivity activity started

6- Home Service reads a 1

7- **Home Service stops, alert screen 1 activity will not start**

If the phone will not start the activity if I unlock the phone after starting the activity on a locked screen either. I can start alert screen activities 2 or 3 after that, but not alert screen 1.

If I run my app with the screen unlocked, everything works fine.

---

Alerts Screen 1 Activity's onCreate

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_yellow_flash);
```

---

Home Service onStartCommand
This service is started, but the thread does all the work. When the thread scans in a value of 1, I call a method to start a new activity. This methods last line interrupts the thread, which in turn stops the service.

```
    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startID){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent PI = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notify_lockout)
            .setContentTitle("Lockout Application")
            .setContentText("Running Services...")
            .setContentIntent(PI).build();

    Random random = new Random();
    int notificationID = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

    startForeground(notificationID, notification);

    // Start Thread
    thread = new Thread(new Threader(startID));
    thread.start();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

The thread calls the startActivity() method, which looks like:

```
startAssistanceAlertActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(startAssistanceAlertActivity);
                Log.e("Test", "Called startActivity");
```

During the failure to start the activity, the Test log is visible in the logcat. So, I just have to wonder why the activity will start once, but never again, regardless of me unlocking the phone.

Any ideas on this? Please let me know if you'd like to see some specific code.

Comment: `Home Service and mainActivity are running in background with phone locked` note : activities don't run in the background.

Comment: I guess what i'm trying to say is that the service is running with the screen locked.

Comment: You might try to clear stack of activities each time service reads your values, e.g: `Alert Service reads in a 0` -> clear `Alert Screen 1`

Comment: @Ibrahim I was using "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" when returning back from the alert screen and it did not work. However, additionally adding that flag to the alert screen fixed to issue. I knew it would be something this simple, and I tried to fix it for days! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome, do you need to receive it as answer? to help OP?

Comment: When you have the time you should. I'll come back to accept your answer. Helping OP is always the right choice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Identifying issue:**

You started `Alert Screen 1 activity` for first time using [`startActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) and it's work also activity added to the stack.

If you try start it again it does't show up.

**Why that happening?**

Using `startActivity()` for the first time will pop-up the activity because it's not on the stack, second time it's only will added to the top of stack, therefore if you tried to lunch the app from icon, it will be display this activity.

**Solution:**

Clear it from stack each time you start other service or use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` while you to start activity.